# chance of picking a number in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code and i am trying to get it to have a 60% chance of picking a 3 if the time is less than 12.
code:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
from random import choice
am = [1, 2, 3]
pm = [1, 2]
datetime.time(datetime.now())
c =(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S %p'))
if c < '12:00:00 PM':
    ch = choice(am)
else:
    ch = choice(pm)
if ch == 1:
    print "hello"
if ch == 2:
    print "how are you?"
if ch == 3:
    print "good morning"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a 60% chance of picking 3 in list `am`, you can edit the list so that 60% of the values are 3.

```
am = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `weights` attribute to set the chances of a certain member being picked.

For example:

```
import random

nums = [1, 2, 3]
result = random.choices(nums, weights=[20, 20, 60])

print (result)
```

If you run it through a `while` loop like so:

```
import random

nums = [1, 2, 3]

while True:
    #update Result value every loop run
    result = random.choices(nums, weights=[20, 20, 60])
    print (result)
```

The value will be updated every time. Happy programming!